# ASP.NET session expired

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer, session-state

I am seeing an exception logged in my error logs which is `Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.AspNetSessionExpiredExceptionAsp.net`.

But I am not being able to reproduce it. After doing google search I understood that it is because of session expiring.

My question is, what would be some reasons for this error and is there any way I can reproduce it by manually clearing the session?

Error log:

> 15/12/2015
>   09:08:11Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.AspNetSessionExpiredException:
>   ASP.NET session has expired or could not be found    at
>   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ViewerDataOperation..ctor()    at
>   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportDataOperation..ctor(Boolean
>   requiresFullReportLoad)    at
>   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler.GetHandler(String
>   operationType)    at
>   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context)    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)   at
>   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ViewerDataOperation..ctor()    at
>   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportDataOperation..ctor(Boolean
>   requiresFullReportLoad)    at
>   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler.GetHandler(String
>   operationType)    at
>   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context)    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set session timeout value in your webconfig that is the way you can check it

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
     <sessionState timeout="20"></sessionState>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks Pranay. But I had set this timeout to 10. But it didnt work.

Comment: may be refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33229796/increase-the-time-of-asp-net-forms-authentication-even-i-change-time-in-web-conf/33230100#33230100